# Is the GNU C++ library missing an unordered_map constructor?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unordered-map

At least [one C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/unordered_map/) lists following constructor signature:

```
explicit unordered_map ( const allocator_type& alloc );
```

It seems that it is not included in `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h`, though. At least I can't spot it and the compiler can't find it, as well.

Thus, my question: Is this constructor specified by the C++ standard? Is the GNU C++ library implementation of unordered_map violating the standard in that respect?

Comment: While we're at it, try getting friendly with [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: @Kos, are those projects related? What are the advantages of cppreference?

Comment: No, they are unrelated. I've personally found cppreference much better organised and more up-to-date with C++11 coverage (but that was a while ago, maybe cplusplus has improved since then). Try it out and see which one works for you

Comment: @maxschlepzig: cppreference is maintained by an open community, so mistakes tend to be fixed as soon as someone notices them. cplusplus has been somewhat unreliable in the past, and was rather slow in updating for C++11, but seems generally fine these days. I use both, and check the Standard if they disagree with each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this constructor specified by the C++ standard?

Yes.

> Is the GNU C++ library implementation of unordered_map violating the standard in that respect?

Yes.

Comment: G++ (version 4.7.2) seems to be missing all of the constructors which require an allocator.  (It has those where the allocator has a default argument.)